# Postgresql: Optimize an update with join

Tags: postgresql, join, optimization, inner-join, postgresql-9.4

I need to update a Postgres table that contains many rows. A way to optimize it, is to compute some fields in a temporary table, then update my main table with the results.

The last step (the main table update) can be very slow when there are millions of rows in my table. This is done with:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET myfield=tmp_mytable.myfield, 
       myfieldtwo=tmp_mytable.myfieldtwo  
FROM tmp_mytable 
WHERE mytable.mypk = tmp_mytable.mypk;
```

The update is done in a batch, so I create the  tmp_mytable with 10 000 rows, then update only 10 000 of mytable at the same time.

When there are few rows (< 5 millions), it needs only few seconds. But with more than 10 millions, each iteration needs between 15 and 30 seconds.

In my understanding, slowness is due to the index update (as postgres creates internally a new row at each update, that needs to be reindexed). However I need indexes in order to compute some of "myfields", also for the join to be efficient.

By need I create indexes with

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY on mytable(myfield)
```

But the CONCURRENTLY is useless for performances.

Is there any tip to boost the update, or maybe avoid to recompute the indexes (these are not needed by my computations)?

EDIT: the EXPLAIN of the final update is

```
Update on mytable  (cost=0.42..61854.23 rows=8265 width=732)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..61854.23 rows=8265 width=732)
    ->  Seq Scan on tmp_mytable  (cost=0.00..517.65 rows=8265 width=270)
    ->  Index Scan using mytable_pkey on mytable  (cost=0.42..7.41 rows=1 width=580)
          Index Cond: ((mytable_id)::text = (tmp_scene. mytable_id)::text)
```

Comment: `concurrently` has no impact on the _usage_ of an index. It is only relevant during the creating of the index and will allow write access to the table for which the index is created.

Comment: `WHERE mytable.mypk = tmp_mytable.mypk;` I presume these are PKs, and thus have unique indexes?

Comment: Yes these are. From my tests, the join is not the problem. If I disable the indexes it processes very faster (but after a while, it doesn't use index anymore and it slows down...)

Comment: We need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query to answer that question.

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN result